# Whenever I open specific Excel binary file computer turns off without warning

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2003

[image]

Whenever I open an Excel binary file my computer turns off without warning.

Even after repairing office the same issue persists.

I can open other Excel files.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: In all my years using computers, and they are many, I've realized that almost every time I have ever clicked something, and then seen my screen go immediately black (rebooting), its been because I was pasting into excel. Its a kernel crash of some kind (nothing else in software can cause that kind of critical failure), but no, I've never come up with any solution to it. Try opening the problematic document on another system, change somthing minor and save it again. then see if it works better for you on the problem system.

Comment: This is critical software error, posible made by hardware failure or not well configured. Have a look here: [read carefully first answer](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/microsoft-error-0x8000000000000002/c8174075-37fd-4e9b-b9ff-4d4db099bbcb?auth=1) Also what are software and version you trying to open the file?

Comment: Disable automatic reboot after BSOD, perhaps you can gather some info (numbers, file names) from there.

Comment: Note that the message you posted is logged after the reboot has occurred. If you want to discover more about your error, you will have the examine the entries immediately preceding this message. don't be suprised if there isn;t one though. black-screen shutdowns usually occur due to hardware problems that don't so much crash the system, but instead make it disappear instantly, without any ability to log.